# C# Timer to check if multithreading is finished fails

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

im using a timer to check if multithreading has finished its calculations.
I have a list of elements that i use to calculate and a listview where I add each calculated element. So the result of the Multithreading should be that the count of listview elements is equal to the count of elements of my list. The multithreading does the calculations.

So i use a timer which will check every 10 seconds if the count of listview elements is equal to the count of list elements and if so it will give an alert.

This is also partly works but the problem is that i get around 15 alerts and not just one alert. I also tried to use a block varaiable like this:

```
if(!block)
{
   Alert();
   block = true;
}
```

But i still get around 15 Alerts.
Important to say is that the timer is(or should be) not part of the multithreading method and will called the first time after multithreading started and not in the multithreading method.

Comment: Have a look at async/await

Comment: I have a feeling your issue is in the details.  Might be helpful if you post more code.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the timer for purposes like showing the user how long it took, then do this.

```
    class Program
    {
        static List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();

        static int maxElements = 400_000;

        static Random random = new Random();

        static int portionSize;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GenerateBytes();

            portionSize = maxElements / 4;

            ParallelLoopResult result = Parallel.For(0, 4, n =>
             {
                 int portion = n * portionSize;
                 for (int i = portion; i < portion + portionSize; i++)
                 {
                     bytes[i] = (byte)(bytes[i] * 2);
                 }
             });

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static void GenerateBytes()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxElements; i++)
            {
                bytes.Add((byte)random.Next(0, 11));
            }
        }
```

Calculating 400,000 elements were pretty fast on my machine since I have 4 cores. Hope this helps!